# Get UIActivityViewController (share) to show on iPad in the way it shows on iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a share button. When the share button is tapped, the view controller runs code like this:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBOutlet weak var popOverView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func share()
{
    let text = "Sharing."
    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    {
        let items = [text,url] as [Any]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        if let popoverViewController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController
        {
            popoverViewController.sourceView = popOverView
            // popoverViewController.sourceRect = popOverView.frame
        }
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print(activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView)
    }
}
```

}

This works, but produces this:

[image: Weird iPad image]

when I want something like this, because the content to be shared won't be on this view controller:

[image: iPhone UIActivityView]

How do I get the screen that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that is **not possible** on iPad.

Sorry for the bad news!

---

If you truly, truly wanted that look, you'd have to make a completely custom view controller that sits down there (ie, no connection to UIActivityViewController), of course that would be an unrealistic amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this:

```
sharingViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
```

before you set the `sharingViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView` property.  `sharingViewController.popoverPresentationController` is nil until you do this.

Comment: Try adding `self.descriptionVC.popoverPresentationController!.permittedArrowDirections = .any` and `self.descriptionVC.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = myRect` where myRect is the CGRect (in self.view's coordinate system) of the the UI element the popover should be "popping" from.

Comment: If that works, let me know in another comment and I will edit my original answer.

Comment: Sorry, what's descriptionVC/myRect?

Comment: @guywithmazda , the iPhone style popup is not possible on iPad.

Comment: @MontanaBurr, I copied and pasted some code from one of my apps and I forgot to change the view controller name to match what you were using. In any case, now that you’ve changed your question title and modified the question itself, I can see that this will not give you the look you were going for.